# Retain time stamp of a downloaded file in FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, timestamp

I'm able to download file from FTP server. Now I want to save that file retaining the time of the file in the ftp server. How can I do that in c#?

example:
**FILE NAME:** File1.gz
**DATE:** 8/16/2014 8:00:00 AM

I'll download File1.gz today which is 8/18/2014 but I want to save the date of my download as 8/16/2014 8:00:00 AM.

What I mean is how can I save to make my file date same as the file date in the ftp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily set the creation date of a file with this:

```
File.SetCreationTime("File1.gz", someDate);
```

More usage and example can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31274/Change-File-Date-Attributes).

Comment: Thanks.i'll try this one. Do you know how can I able to know the file date of a file inside a zip file?

Comment: @KuriyamaMirai Look into ZIP libraries. You should be able to get the meta-data of the ZIP and the items inside it as well as extract it within the code.

Comment: It do work. All i have to do is to get the time stamp of files in ftp server and set it to the modified and creation date of my downloaded file. Thank you so much

Comment: What i mean is when the file is still in the ftp server. When I downloaded the file, the date of the extracted file is the same as date when I downloaded it not the origonal date it was uploaded in the ftp server.

Comment: Oh I see. You should open a new question about how to get the time stamp from the ftp server if you are having trouble finding the answer on the web.